# Who is Randolph Morgan that HR mentioned while using his face?

Tags: character, arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash*, s3 e6, named [*Shade*](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Shade), HR aka the Harrison Wells from Earth 19 took up a new face with his Earth's *light refraction* technology and mentioned that it was of "*Randolph Morgan*".

He mentioned this name again in the course of the episode and also made up a name based on this viz. "H.R. *Morgan*" before Cecile to keep his identity secret.

Well, I googled a bit and at the first sight, saw no significant character of this name.

So, is *Randolph Morgan* some character in the DC comics or some other person related to Wells or Flash?

In a word what is is whereabouts? Or is the name arbitrarily made up by HR for no reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He says in that scene

> HR: "What you've just been witness to is my partner's likeness, Randolph Morgan."

In the previous episode, "Monster," HR comes clean about his lack of scientific credentials, telling the group:

> HR: "There are two parts to every idea: the inception, and the execution. I provide the former."

and

> Caitlin: "So you didn't actually solve the cryptogram that we sent you?"
>   HR: "No. That was my partner at Star Labs. On my earth I'm the face of the company. I'm more of the inspiration behind the company."

I don't see a reference in that episode to the name. Just "my partner." I and others have noted that Earth-1 Wells' wife and partner was "Tess Morgan," same last name, so I imagine there is more to be told on this tale.

Comment: Is there any character of the same name in the comics or is it just a random name they made for the show?

Comment: Not that I can find, but I and others have noted that Well's wife from Earth-1 in the show was "Tess Morgan," same last name. I imagine there is more yet to be told on this story.

Comment: That's a very good point; please add this in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

When Tess Morgan was first introduced in The Flash, many theorized that she may actually be Tess *Mercer*, Lionel Luthor's illegitimate daughter. This theory was, of course, proven wrong when it was revealed that Supergirl takes place in a separate universe than The Flash. The writer's were sure to take special care to hammer this detail out when they introduced Lena Luthor, who was also known as Tess Mercer.

All that aside, there is actually a rather extensive family in the DC universe that carries the last name "Morgan". No one in that family is named either Randolph or Tess, but that doesn't necessarily mean much. In addition, Travis Morgan (the head of the Morgan family), has a connection to Green Arrow, so there is a chance that someone from the Morgan family will come into play at some point in the future.

Comment: That's a nice info; +1. Also welcome in the Movies&TV SE @rathaway.